# Redirect utm_source for multilingual web page

Tags: .htaccess

I have https://www.example.com/page-name/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter

I have added the following code in the .htaccess file and redirected it to https://www.example.com/page-name/.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(utm_source) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

But the multilingual page is not redirected with this code.

Now, how can I redirect a multilingual page?

`https://www.example.com/ar/page-name/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter`

to

`https://www.example.com/ar/page-name/`

or

`https://www.example.com/fr/page-name/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter`

to

`https://www.example.com/fr/page-name/`

Anyone, please help me.